# PeekNamedPipe always returns 0 for totalBytesAvailable

Tags: c, windows, named-pipes

```
  PeekNamedPipe( 
    tmp_pipe,                // __in       HANDLE hNamedPipe, 
    NULL,                  // __out_opt  LPVOID lpBuffer, 
    0,                     // __in       DWORD nBufferSize, 
    NULL,                  // __out_opt  LPDWORD lpBytesRead, 
    &totalBytesAvailable,  // __out_opt  LPDWORD lpTotalBytesAvail, 
    NULL                   // __out_opt  LPDWORD lpBytesLeftThisMessage 
  );
```

I have written bytes to the pipe somewhere else,but totalBytesAvailable is always `0`,why?

Comment: Which language are you using?  Are you sure the function or previous function calls did not return an error?

Answer (score 3):

I have found that in Windows, if you call `PeekNamedPipe` before calling `ReadFile`, it will always return zero bytes, even if there are in fact bytes to be read. You have to call  `ReadFile`, followed by `PeekNamedPipe`, and keep looping until `PeekNamedPipe` returns zero bytes.

I have noticed that even under these circumstances, sometimes `PeekNamedPipe` returns zero bytes even though there are bytes left to be gotten. Must be a timing thing. The sender is going to have to preface each message with a byte count. Sigh...

Comment: Use ReadFile 0 bytes when std_input_handle is in file_type_disk worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but I haven't found the answer online so I figured I'd answer it anyway. You have to loop until the pipe reads, here's my working code:

```
DWORD bytesAvail = 0;
while(bytesAvail==0){
    if( !PeekNamedPipe(pipeHandle, NULL, 0, NULL, &bytesAvail, NULL) ){
        printf("PeekNamedPipe error %d.\n", GetLastError()); //error check
    }
} 
printf("Bytes available: %d\n", bytesAvail);
```

Of course, this only works if you are sure there is data waiting to be read, otherwise you will be stuck in an endless loop because there isn't actually data to be read, so it will always be 0.

Comment: Why do you need to loop until the pipe read? the `PeekNamedPipe()` itself block until the read is done. If you want to block until there's some data to read you may just call  `ReadFile()` in blocking mode, i.e, `PIPE_WAIT` in `CreateFile()`

Comment: Punctiliousness: DWORD bytesAvail = 0;

Comment: This doesn't answer the problem. The problem is that PeekNamedPipe always returns zero bytes available, even when there are bytes available.