# ReadFromFile C++ With unknown bytesRead size

Tags: c++, windows, pipe, handle

I'm using the Microsoft example on how to pass data from a called process using a handle to the parent process.

Here is my createChild function

```
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

//output file for hash rate
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &sa, 0);
SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);



si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
si.hStdInput = NULL;
si.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
si.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;



si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;

int success;

success = CreateProcess((appPath + L"\\" + processName + L".exe").c_str(),
        cmdArgs,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        TRUE,
        CREATE_NO_WINDOW,
        NULL,
        appPath.c_str(),
        &si,
        &pi)
        ;
//}

CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
```

Once the child is created it never terminates.  It runs and sends output to the parent for as long as the PC is running.

Every five minutes the parent calls this function to grab the buffer.

```
void Helpers::ReadFromPipe(CHAR* chBuf)
{
DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
HANDLE hParentStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
for (;;)
{
    bSuccess = ReadFile(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, 4096, &dwRead, NULL);
    if (!bSuccess || dwRead == 0) break;

    bSuccess = WriteFile(hParentStdOut, chBuf,
        dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
    if (!bSuccess) break;
}
return;
}
```

Sometimes it works and other times it doesn't.
When it gets stuck in the for loop is that because I set a bytes to read too high?

My called process writes 5 lines of text out so about 100 bytes or so.  But the lines are varied on each run so I can't be 100% sure how much to set the bytes to read number at.

Comment: Step through the code, line by line, in a debugger. *Where* does it "gets stuck"?

Comment: How did you open the `g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd` handle? You can investigate about `OVERLAPPED` mode and `PIPE_NOWAIT` to use an asynchronous approach.

Comment: No, the problem is very unlikely to be caused by reading too many bytes.  (Well, unless the buffer isn't big enough?)  But I think the break condition is wrong; zero bytes read is not an "end of pipe" condition.  My best guess is that you aren't closing your handle to the child's end of the pipe.  But we'd need a [mcve] to be sure.

Comment: Sorry I added the rest of my code now. Currently stepping through line by line to see the exact line it gets hung up on.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you were expecting `ReadFile` to be non-blocking, which it isn't.

The most straightforward solution is to run the loop in a separate thread.  The overhead of this approach is minimal, since you only need one thread per child process, and the child process uses *far* more system resources than the thread does.

One variation on that is to use asynchronous I/O, with notifications going to your main thread.  This is both more elegant and more efficient, but can involve considerably more work and is not not likely to have any significant practical advantages in your case.  (I mention it only because someone is bound to complain if I don't.)

[*For completeness:* yet another variation is using a non-blocking pipe.  This is a legacy technology, kept only for backwards compatibility, and Microsoft strongly recommend that it should not be used in new code.  It has no significant advantages over using a separate thread.]

---

Your existing code is almost correct if you were to run it in a separate thread.  The loop should look something like this:

```
for (;;)
{
    bSuccess = ReadFile(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, 4096, &dwRead, NULL);
    if (!bSuccess)
    {
       DWORD err = GetLastError();
       if (err == ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE) break; // All data has been read
       fail(err);
    }
    bSuccess = WriteFile(hParentStdOut, chBuf, dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
    if (!bSuccess) fail(GetLastError());
}
```

and you need to call `CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr);` after the call to `CreateProcess`.  That ensures that the only handle to the write end of the pipe is the handle the child process has inherited; when the child exits, the handle will be closed and the pipe will break.  (This is safe for an anonymous pipe; for the record, the rules for named pipes are a little more complicated.)

---

Now, let's look at the case where you wait for the child process to exit before retrieving the output.  You don't need a separate thread in this case, unless you need to perform other operations while waiting for the child to exit.  The code shown above only exits when the child does [see footnote] so you can perform the wait and retrieve the data at the same time.

If you are waiting for the child to exit at the same time as doing some other task, you can either assume that all the output will fit into the pipe buffer, use a separate thread to retrieve the output, or use asynchronous I/O.  Depending on how your existing code is structured, asynchronous I/O may be a good choice here, but a separate thread is usually easier.

Since there are no guarantees about the size of the pipe buffer, assuming that the output will fit may cause a deadlock, with the child waiting for the parent to read from the pipe and the parent waiting for the child to exit.

[*Footnote:* technically, the loop will also exit if the child closes the pipe handles, though that's unusual.  In that case, the child won't be able to write any more data, so you'll know you've got all the output.  But if you must be sure that the child has actually exited, you'll want to check for that separately, *after* the pipe has broken.]

---

I know of no straightforward way to deal with the case where you want to check for available input periodically.  In principle you should be able to use `PeekNamedPipe` to see how much data is available, [but it seems that this does not work as expected.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38000448/886887)

If you can control the output from the child, a zero-length write will cause the `ReadFile` in the parent to exit with zero bytes read, or you could pad the output to a fixed length.  This still requires the parent to know when to expect input from the child so is not a good general solution.  Also, it may break if the child process generates any unexpected output, e.g., from the C runtime library.

The only other sensible options that I can see are to use a separate thread or asynchronous I/O, as discussed previously.

Comment: Thanks I tried it and for some reason dwRead is coming out to 0, even though I call the readpipe function after waiting for the process to finish.   In my child process the way I'm sending the data is via fprintf(stdout, "%s", temp.c_str());   Is that the proper way to do so?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear I have two versions of the project. One never terminates the child and does wait until the buffer is filled before proceeding, my solution to that was to pad the buffer with 0's in the child process.  I have another version where the child terminates then the readfrompipe function is called. In that version no data is extracted from the buffer/read

Comment: I've rewritten my answer to address both the issue in PeekNamedPipe and your clarification of the scenario.